# How do I get the users role to check what it is?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

So i am developing my first ASP.NET COre 3.0 MVC application and I just got into `Identity` and now I want to display the users role in a list here is what I did.

```
@model CoreBuddyLite.ViewModel.UserManagementIndexViewModel
 <tbody>
        @foreach (var user in Model.Users)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@user.UserName</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
```

if I were to try to do `@user.R` then Role or Roles doesnt exist. I am 90% sure that it did exist in previous versions at least in ASP.NET Core 1.0.

How do I properly get the Role assigned to a user?

```
public class UserManagementIndexViewModel
{
    public List<UserAccount> Users { get; set; }
}
```

And I shouldn't have to add it as a property in my UserAccount class since it derrives from IdentityUser

```
public class UserAccount : IdentityUser
{

}
```

Comment: Why don't you create a stored procedure that returns all the roles against a user's id?

Comment: I could but apparently `Role` isn't a part of the IdentityUser or am I missing something?

Comment: That's true, but AspNetUserRoles usually has a foreign key to AspNetUser using the user's ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IdentityUser` and `IdentityRole` are two separate types.

As JamesS points out, there is a composite join between `Users` and `Roles`. You can find that in the table `AspNetUserRoles`. It links the `AspNetUsers` and `AspNetUserRoles` tables together.

I don't think Entity Framework comes standard in ASP.NET CORE 3, but if you are using it already, you can use a `_context` object (`ApplicationDbContext`) in your controller to build your list using the fluent API and `Include()` & `ThenInclude()` methods.

Otherwise, you may want to just go the stored procedure or view route in SQL as suggested.

However, keep in mind that an `ApplicationUser` might have many roles, so your razor view will have to include a nested `foreach()` loop.

Working with version 3 is not for the faint of heart, I admire your diligence.